# how to import external repository into a shared web server folder

Tags: php, git

I am a new git user.

I have a repository on bitbucket that I would like to import into a .git folder I have created on my live shared host web server ( where I have git installed ). I can give commands via SSH. I am trying to create the PRIME directory as listed in http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/

Any ideas on the specific git command. currently my .git target folder is empty.

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that PRIME in a non-bare repository that is pulled from HUB's master branch. So, have PRIME pull from HUB every so often should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm looking for is the actual code to use. In the article he discusses: $ git commit -m"initial import of pre-existing web files" what is "initial import of pre-existing web files"? - Bill

Comment: That's the commit message, can be anything, except blank.

Comment: but surely the files must be pulled from somewhere. I have a bit bucket repository with address git@bitbucket.org:***/***.git. Do I do for example git commit -m git@bitbucket.org:***/***.git "initial import of pre-existing web files" to pull the repository into my empty directory. ( that didn't work BTW )  - Thanks - Bill

Comment: PRIME and HUB are URLs. I don't know your particular setup, but I would guess that HUB is the bitbucket repository and PRIME is your website.

Comment: to quote the article:

"The key idea in this system is that the web site exists on the server as a pair of repositories; a bare repository alongside a conventional repository containing the live site. Two simple Git hooks link the pair, automatically pushing and pulling changes between them.  "    from reading further, they discuss the exact commands used and I am 99% sure these imply both repos are on the server. do you disagree?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the repositories happen to be.

Comment: Ok , well using your advice I have set up both repos on the server . Thanks for your help. Regards - Bill